# Trying to populate sql table with html form

Tags: php, html, sql

Im trying to create a new row in the table 'Colaboradores' but it doesn't populate, but when i 'echo' the '$sql' with works fine along with the connection. I already check the name of the columns in the sql table. Im using MAMP as a sever

```
 <?php
       include("../../config.php");
       session_start();

       if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {

    $nomeF = $_POST['nomeF']; 
    $nomeL = $_POST['nomeL'];
    $Prof = $_POST['Profissao'];
    $morada = $_POST['morada'];
    $cod = $_POST['cod'];
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $ordeb = $_POST['ordb'];
    $orde = $_POST['orde'];
    $dataI = $_POST['dataI'];
    $dataF = $_POST['dataF'];
    $notas1 = $_POST['notas1'];
    $notas2 = $_POST['notas2'];

    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=SCMMM;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO Colaboradores (NomeF, NomeL, Profissao, Morada, CodPostal, Telemovel, mail, precoh, precohmais, dataI, dataF, notas1, notas2) 
      VALUES (:nomeF, :nomeL, :Prof, :morada, :cod, :num, :mail, :ordeb, :orde, :dataI, :dataF, :notas1, :notas2)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue('nomeF', $nomeF, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('nomeL', $nomeL, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('Prof', $Prof, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('morada', $morada, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('cod', $cod, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('num', $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue('mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('ordb', $ordeb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue('orde', $orde, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue('dataI', $dataI, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('dataF', $dataF, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('notas1', $notas1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue('notas2', $notas2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

       }

    ?>
```

Comment: Have you noticed column names & values count mismatch here in insert query?

Comment: You better show not `echo 'Erro';` but `mysqli_error($db);` and will see an error.

Comment: if `mysqli_query()` returns false, you have an error in your SQL. Simple as that. And that you're wide open to SQL injection doesn't make it better.

Comment: also, start looking into `SQL injection` and how to defend against it!

Comment: Yes i checked the column name and the values in the insert query

Comment: I also try mysqli_error($db); but didn't show any error

Comment: You have 11 columns in your `INSERT` list, but 12 values in your `VALUES`.  My guess is that `$morada` isn't needed?

Comment: "but didn't show any error" ...did you echo the result of it, i.e. `if(!mysqli_query($db,$sql)){
           echo mysqli_error($db);
}` ? There's a problem with your query, so there should be an error visible from there

Comment: Also, others have talked about SQL injection. It's true - your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Here's some practical advice: you should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. I suggest you take a look at them (and others available online) and modify your code accordingly. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like that.

Comment: It show an error of SQL syntax that doesn't correspond to my MySQL server version

Comment: Thx i will take a look but for now i just want to solve this first and then i will parameterise my  query

Comment: "It show an error of SQL syntax"...please show us exactly what is is. What do you mean it doesn't correspond to your MySQL version? It's not clear, please explain

Comment: This is the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Nome, Ultimo Nome, Profissão, Morada, Codigo Postal, Telemovel, mail, precoh, p' at line 1"

Comment: ok so it's just saying you have a syntax error. The "corresponds" bit is telling you to look at the right version of the manual in order to check what the correct syntax is for the statement you're executing. It's not actually telling you what version you have or haven't got. You should already know that. I would guess that the `+` in the field name is the problem. Try putting it in backticks i.e. `\`precoh+\``. Once you fix that then next you'll get an error because you're trying to insert 12 values into 11 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily improve your code :

- Avoid symbol as `ã` or `+` in database
- Avoid space in database (replace by `_`)
- Inform yourself about OOP and PDO
- Inform yourself about SQL injection, Prepare query, ...
- Use a convention for your variables names, lower camelcase ? upper camelcase ? whatever but stay regular

Now try with this code

```
$nomeF = $_POST['nomeF']; 
$nomeL = $_POST['nomeL'];
$descP = $_POST['descP'];
$morada = $_POST['morada'];
$num = $_POST['num'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$dataI = $_POST['dataI'];
$dataF = $_POST['dataF'];
$ordeb = $_POST['ordeb'];
$orde = $_POST['orde'];
$notas1 = $_POST['notas1'];
$notas2 = $_POST['notas2'];

try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO Colaboradores (nomeF, nomeL, descP, morada, mail, ordeb, orde, dataI, dataF, notas1, notas2) 
  VALUES (:nomeF, :nomeL, :descP, :morada, :num, :mail, :ordeb, :orde, :dataI, :dataF, :notas1, :notas2)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('nomeF', $nomeF, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('nomeL', $nomeL, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('descP', $descP, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('morada', $morada, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('num', $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('ordeb', $ordeb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('dataI', $dataI, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('dataF', $dataF, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('notas1', $notas1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('notas2', $notas2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

### **EDIT**

I build your project on my computer, try to add

```
$error = $stmt->errorInfo();
print_r($error);
```

To see what's happen during your request.

On my side, I found a mismatch with the word `ordeb` and `ordb`

For example : `$stmt->bindValue('ordb', $ordeb, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

And can you check also the format of your date, it should be "Y-m-d H:i:s")

**Note :** All your columns in your table are of `text` type, text should be used only for long text (like in textarea), you should use `varchar` which allow you to save up to 255 characters (enough).

---

Comment: Thx, but whenever i press submit in the html form it gives this error "localhost stopped working"

Comment: Are you running WAMP (or MAMP/LAMP) ? Are all your services running ? Can you access to phpMyAdmin ? Are you sure about your database credentials ?

Comment: Im using MAMP, the serves are running and i can access to phpMyAdmin also the credentials are correct

Comment: I solve the problem but, now every time i press submit i check the table in phpMyAdmin and doesn't appear a new row in the table.

Comment: Try to apply my tips list (no symbols, no spaces) for column names, it should fix your "error syntax"

Comment: Could you show us your new code ? And your database structure ?

Comment: This is the error that gives "Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1048 [2] => Column 'NomeF' cannot be null )"

Comment: Ok so change the structure of `NomeF` to `nullable` or check your variable because it's null (maybe your `$_POST`)